# Reverse proxy multiple backend web servers

Tags: squid, reverse-proxy

I am trying to have multiple copies of the same web application appear under different paths of a single URL.  Each application is a unique instance with its own login.  All run with http.

In this example John, Jane and Jerry all have their own instance on different servers.  I don't know if the apps support a host http header yet so I would like to proxy requests and rewrite the links in the html.

I have tried using tinyproxy but the website ends up redirecting.  I have also tried using squid but couldn't get it to work either.

A visual representation of what I am trying to do:

```
Request: http://example.com:5002/john_server/

---> example.com (listening ports 5000, 5001, 5002)
      +
      |
      +----+john_server.local (5000, 5001, 5002)
      |
      |
      +----+jane_server.local (5000, 5001, 5002)
      |
      |
      +----+jerry_server.local (5000, 5001, 5002)
```

Does anyone know how to configure tinyproxy or squid to do this?  Is it even possible?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

You can make a reverse proxy with nginx. It's a common use case and simple to set up. https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/